# What is the probability that the message consists of $2 A$’s , $2 B$’s, and $1 C\;$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A message of length $5$ letters is to be sent. You can pick three letters $A$, $B$ and $C$ to make a message of length $5$. So the total sample space is $243 = 3^5$

Two Questions:

- What is the probability of that the message consists of $2 A$’s , $2 B$’s and $1 C$ ?
- And what is the probability that it contains at least $1 A$ in the message ?

First Question:
At first I thought it was ${5\choose2} + {5\choose2}+ 5 = 10 + 10 + 5 = 25$. So the probability  $25/243 = 0.1029 $ or ${5\choose2} + {5\choose2} = 20$, so the probability is $20/243 = 0.082$ but  that wasn’t correct.

Help wanted for both questions.

Hints, proof or answer.

Comment: Are all $243$ messages equally probable?

Comment: Yes, they are al equally probable

Comment: You should never change a question after any answer(s) has been received as it invalidates the answer(s)

Comment: To clarifie: “has at least one A” is changed to “contains at least one A”.  So its not a big change. The major change : adding “at least” was made after the question was made. See comment by John’s answer, 8 hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways of having two A's, two B's, and one C is

$$\pmatrix{5\\2}\pmatrix{3\\2}=10\cdot 3= 30.$$

There are five positions for the A's.  Once they are filled, there are three positions for the B's.  The C will go in the remaining spot.

So $$p= \frac{30}{3^5} = \frac{30}{243} =\frac{10}{81}=0\overline{.123456790}$$

Comment: 5 chosen 3 is also 10? So 10*10 is 100.

Comment: sorry about that.  edited the second "term".  After the A's are chosen, there remain only three spots for the two B's.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints.

1. Assume you have an arrangement with the required letters. How many ways can you place the $A$s? From there, how many ways can you place the $B$s? What about the $C$?
2. It may be better to count all of the ways that there are *no* $A$s, and subtract from the total $243$.

Can you make some headway now?

Spoiler:

> 1) There are $5\choose 2$ ways to place the $A$s. Then there are $3\choose 2$ ways to place the $B$s. The $C$ goes in the last place. So $10 \times 3 \times 1 = 30$ possibilities. 2) There are $2^5 = 32$ messages that contain only $B$s and $C$s, so all of the others contain at least one $A$.

Comment: Thanks John for the hints. Second question is at least one A and yes uou have to calculate P(no A’s) and substract that of 1 or i think so. But it’s better to count non A’s and substract that of 243 and take that answer and divide it by 243 to get the probability?

Comment: Question one: i thought ${5\choose2} $ was the count or ways the A’s fit in the message, after that the B’s: also  ${5\choose2}$. I wrote them all out and got 25. What i’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  The actual *question* **has been changed**.  Please find below an answer to the original question.  You can take this as a 'hint' to solving the new question.  Also, I agree, the new question is best solved by enumerating number of possibilities with "no A's".

The second question asks (asked!) "What if there is one A?".  If so, these are the possibilities:

$$\{A,C,C,C,C\}$$
$$\{ A, B, C,C,C \}$$
$$\{ A, B, B,C,C \}$$
$$\{ A, B,B,B,C\}$$
$$\{A, B,B,B,B\}$$

along with all the permutations of these.

That would be:

$$\begin{aligned}\pmatrix{5\\1}+ \pmatrix{5\\1}\pmatrix{4\\1}+\pmatrix{5\\1}\pmatrix{4\\2}+ \pmatrix{5\\1}\pmatrix{4\\3} + \pmatrix{5\\1} &= 5\cdot\left(1+4+6+4+1\right)\\&=80 \end{aligned}$$

so $$P(\text{one }A)=\frac{80}{243}\approx 0.329218$$

Comment: Note that the OP has now been edited to clarify the condition as having *at least* one A.

Comment: Well, that's great!  This way, my answer can be taken as a hint:  What if there is exactly 1 A.  I don't think everybody/anybody wants me (or anybody else) to change the answer every time somebody changes the question.  Do you?

Comment: No, not really, but I thought I'd point it out, because it seemed unlikely you'd notice otherwise.

Comment: No, i have clarified the question more! If you see my comment by the hints of John, you can see that i said at least one, and so i claried it more.

Comment: Thanks mjw for the answer, and yes it can be taken as a hint!

Comment: On the answer given: the correct answer is (5chosen5)+(5chosen1)+(5chosen2)+(5chosen3)+(5chosen4)+(5chosen5)= 32. So 1- (32/243)= 0.868

Comment: Thanks for the answer mjw!

Comment: Sure, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I like to approximate answers to such problems by using simulation. Sometimes one can overlook or double-count possibilities using combinatorial methods.
Simulations with a million iterations usually give two or three decimal places of accuracy--good enough to catch some mistakes.

Some initial confusion here due to change in the question, but no errors remain: (+1's to all).

To simulate your problem, I will have three kinds of tokens instead of `A`, `B`, and `C`, Instead, Tokens have numbers `100`, `10`, and `1`. So two `A`s, two `B`s and a `C` means a total of `221`. And "At least one `A` means a total greater than `100`.

```
set.seed(2021)
t = replicate(10^6, 
              sum(sample(c(100,10,1),5,rep=T)))

mean(t==221);  mean(t >= 100)
[1] 0.123124   # two A's, two B'2, one C. Aprx 10/81
[1] 0.868125   # at least one A

mean(t > 100 & t < 200);  mean(t < 100)
[1] 0.329126   # exactly one A.  Aprx 80/243
[1] 0.131875   # no A.  Aprx. (2/3)^5 =  0.1317
```

Notes on R code.  Vector `t` has a million totals between 5 and 500. Logical vector `t==221` has
a million `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s; its `mean` is the
proportion of its `TRUE`s. Symbol `&` means intersection.